# Installation Program that Installs a Sys File

Tags: installation, driver

we're trying to create an install package that installs a driver….We need to install this driver as an upper filter to an existing device.

We're looking for an install program that will allow us to do that.  We looked at Installshield and it appears to not do this.

If anyone has any suggestions, it would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks a bunch in advance,

Scott

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for the [DIFx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463103)

it can be used in an msi with a merge module or standalon with an exe and a few parameters.

installshield DOES contain a driver install framework. just create a new component in the gui, rightclick, driver wizard.

Comment: weberik....thanks for the quick answer! Greatly appreciated...Can I hire you to help us with the installation?  Just would want to ask a bunch of questions so we know what we're doing.  If so, please send me an email.  My contact info is on my profile page.  Again...thanks a bunch!

Comment: @the_koch i am no expert on drivers but i can try. but your email address is not visible to me in your profile. maybe you can just post your problems here and we solve it together?